# How to make C-style union

Tags: racket

I can't find out how to make C-style union. In example given in [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/foreign/C_Union_Types.html):

```
(define a-union-type
(_union (_list-struct _int _int)
        (_list-struct _double _double)))
(define a-union-val
    (cast (list 3.14 2.71)
          (_list-struct _double _double)
          a-union-type))
```

all works. But if is cast changed to _int:

```
(define a-union-val
    (cast (list 3 2)
          (_list-struct _int _int)
          a-union-type))
```

I get following error:

```
cast: representation sizes of from and to types differ
  size of from type: 8
  size of to size: 16
```

Which somehow makes sense but question is, how to create this union?

Could you please explain me a difference between make-union-type and _union also? As it is unclear to me from docs.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: 3.14 and 2.71 are not `int`s

Comment: True, but this is not the problem here... Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast only works when `(ctype-sizeof from-type)` equals `(ctype-sizeof to-type)`, so only the largest union variant(s) are allowed. Try using manual allocation and `union-set!` instead:

```
(define a-union-val (ptr-ref (malloc a-union-type) a-union-type))
(union-set! a-union-val 0 (list 3 2))
```

Where the second parameter of `union-set!` is the index of the variant you want.

Comment: Do I need to free that memory by hand?

Comment: @Ondrej Not when using malloc as written here. But depending on what you're doing you may need to use a different malloc mode, and for some modes the answer is yes. Consult the malloc docs, and use `cpointer-gcable?` to find out if memory will be GCd, e.g., `(cpointer-gcable? (union-ptr a-union-val))`.